# Avoid Python CGI browser timeout

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a Python CGI that I use along with `SQLAlchemy`, to get data from a database, process it and return the result in Json format to my webpage.

The problem is that this process takes about 2mins to complete, and the browsers return a time out after 20 or 30 seconds of script execution.

Is there a way in Python (maybe a library?) or an idea of design that can help me let the script execute completely ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You will have to set the timing on the http server's (Apache for 
example) configuration.  The default should be more than 120 seconds, if I remember 
correct.

Comment: Thanks, do you have a link on how I can do this?